# How to Use System.DirectoryServices to Access a Web Server on a Different Domain

Tags: c#, iis-6, directoryservices

I am trying to write a simple program to list the virtual directories of an IIS server, which is on a different domain than my local machine.  When creating the root DirectoryEntry object, I tried to pass in the credentials with a domain qualifier, like this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://myremoteserver/W3SVC/1/Root", "mydomain\\myusername", "mypassword");
```

I get an "Access is Denied" exception, however.  Is this the right way to do this?  All the code examples I've found only access the local web server.
I running WinXP SP3 locally, and trying to connect to a Win2003 R2 (64-bit) server running IIS version 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) classes to do this instead, which works when I use a domain qualifier in the login:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
            options.Username = "somedomain\\username";
            options.Password = "password";
            ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath();
            path.Server = "someserver";
            path.NamespacePath = "root/MicrosoftIISv2";
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);

            string Query = "select * from IIsWebVirtualDirSetting";
            using (ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery(Query)))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj.Properties["Name"].Value);
                }                
            }          
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```